# XSLT renaming child nodes in mixed content

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this structure

```
<root>
  <parent>BLA<child>BLI</child>BLU</parent>
</root>
```

And I want to get this output

```
<root>
  <A_PARENT>BLA<A_CHILD>BLI</A_CHILD>BLU</A_PARENT>
</root>
```

I already got the parent to become `A_PARENT`, but as `parent` can host mixed content, I can't get the `parent`'s text content to be copied and in the same time rename its children whatever the imbrication level.

I could show XSL code here, but there isn't any template that made me close enough from the expected that it would be worth sharing.

Any hints ?

Comment: Maybe showing your XSL-code, even if it's not perfect, would improve your question, nevertheless.

Comment: Even if your code is way off the mark, showing it makes it easier to help you because we get a feel for what you know and what you have yet to learn.

Answer (score 2):

***No special provisions for transforming mixed content are required...***

**A simple application of the identity transformation,**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <A_PARENT>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </A_PARENT>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <A_CHILD>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </A_CHILD>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**applied to your input XML,**

```
<root>
  <parent>BLA<child>BLI</child>BLU</parent>
</root>
```

**yields this output XML,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <A_PARENT>BLA<A_CHILD>BLI</A_CHILD>BLU</A_PARENT>
</root>
```

**as requested.**

Answer (score 1):

There's two tasks here. One is basic, every-day XSLT iteration over nodes by applying templates to them. The other is the dynamic naming of elements.

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='root/*' />
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='*'>
    <xsl:element name='A_{translate(name(), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")}'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

That weird `translate(...` line is a long-winded way of converting to uppercase in XSLT 1.

You can see a demo at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.xyz/o6nvqc) (click the Output tab to see the generated code.)

Note that I have assumed a convention - namely, that all tags, at any level, should be converted to uppercase and prefixed with "A_".

Comment: Thanks all for answers. Had to move to something else for now but will come back to you asap.

Comment: First of all thanks for anwsers. They were all helpful and sure effective. I came with something slightly different due to some larger project specifications.

But as you mostly offered it consisted in having a more generic approach.